# How to open an extenal form modal with Angular.js using multiple views with parallel states

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am developing a one-page application and I'm currently working on the website's navbar. I want to put in the navbar a dropdown menu that lets the user connect/register to the website if he's not currently connected and to logout/change settings if he already logged in.

The website makes use of ngRoute to load the main page content so the page already has a *ng-view* (I read that you can only have one per page).

I would like to open a modal with a login form when the user clicks on the link "Login" in the dropdown menu (and a modal with a registration form when the user clicks on "Register").

I know how to add a modal to the page but I would like to load it from an external template file only the first time the modal is opened (just like the main content view works).

The website will probably have several modals and I don't want to put a lot of hidden modals every-time a page is generated.

As you may have noticed, I'm new to Angular.js, so I'm wondering if the library provides me an easy way to do this.

To explain what I'm trying to do in an easier way:

- I'd ilke to have a */template/loginForm.html* file that contains the login form in a modal
- I'd like have a link in the dropdown menu that loads the file ONLY if it was never loaded before (just like ngRoute does)
- Everytime the link is clicked the modal is opened (URL doesn't change)

I would solve this by adding variables that indicate which modals are already loaded (new modals would be appended to the page with a unique ID) but I'm not sure this would be a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using multiple separate views in the same page (which was my goal). I couldn't do that with the library *ngRoute* so I added *[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)* to my project.

As far as I understood *ui-router* doesn't support multiple separate (no parent-child relations) views in the same page with parallel states (it does support named views but you can't just update one at a time without clearing the others, if I'm not mistaken).

In the end I solved the problem by importing *[ui-router-extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky)* that adds a lot of useful features to *ui-router*. You can see a nice modal example [here](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/index.html#/people/managers) (which is what I was trying to accomplish).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) where you would have possibility of nested states and views.

So you would have your index page

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <a ui-sref="main">Main Page</a>
    <a ui-sref="other">Other Page</a>
</body>
```

Then

```
<!-- partials/main.html -->
<h1>main page</h1>
<hr/>
<a ui-sref="main.login">Login</a>
<a ui-sref="main.register">Register</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Define you login and register page

```
<!-- partials/main.login.html -->
<h3>Login Page</h3>

<!-- partials/main.register.html -->
<h3>Register Page</h3>
```

Controller would be configured as,

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      templateUrl: "partials/main.html"
    })
    .state('main.login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "partials/main.login.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
      }
    })    
    .state('main.register', {
      url: "/register",
      templateUrl: "partials/main.register.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
      }
    });
});
```

Its pretty similar to ngRoute and simple. Detailed instructions are given on [github page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: I read that it is a work-in-progress library and it is subject to change. Also are nested views what I really need?

Comment: Nested views would be useful in your case, I have updated answer

Comment: I noticed the update, thanks. I need the modals to be accessible from every page (the user can click login/register from any page) and the URL shouldn't change, can I do that with the library?

Comment: Yes,I tried this. if you don't provide url parameter to state then url doesn't change but view gets changes. So login state would be `.state('main.login', {
      templateUrl: "partials/main.login.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
      }
    }) `

Comment: I will try this later, is there any reason why it has to be 'main.login' instead of just 'login' or any other name?

Comment: I spent some time switching to *ui-router* and am now using two different *ui-views* and *ui-sref* links. I only have to figure how to change only one view when clicking a link and I should be ok to go, any idea how to do that without parent/child views? Thanks in advance

Comment: ''main.login' its logical parent-child relation, you can even name it with unique 'mainlogin'. Check this [repository](https://github.com/shankargurav/ui-router-example). Your second question is not clear enough if you mean something else.

Comment: I saw your example but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I have two views in the same page like this: `<div ui-view="ContentView"></div><div ui-view="ModalView"></div>`. Certain links should change the URL and the ContentView, certain links should only change the ModalView.

Comment: I discovered the plugin *ui-router-extras* that extends the library *ui-router* and lets you use multiple named views. [Here's an example](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/index.html#/people/managers) (the same thing I'm trying to accomplish).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it would be helpful to me in future.